# Air for iOS - how to handle crashes due to limited memory?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, exception, air, out-of-memory

We're currently developing an iPad application using Air for iOS and from time to time experience crashes (on iPad1 with ios 5 only) which seem to be because the application is using up too much memory.

How to catch/handle such errors in the application? how to be notified when memory is low? trying to catch flash.errors.MemoryError doesn't seem to work. Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

I've done some work in this area and here are some tips that I can give you.

1. **Get Flash Builder 4.6 *Premium***.

   Get it if only for the profiler alone. It has one of the best profilers available for diagnosing things like this. With that said, there are other Flash profilers around, that have varying degrees of usefulness.

   This alone will help you find and diagnose where most of your memory is going in terms of raw memory usage, but also help you find how many objects you are creating and destroying and how long they are hanging around before the garbage collector is finally getting around to letting them go.
2. **Pool smaller trivial objects**

   Rather than constantaly creating and destorying smaller objects, create [object pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). This will save you the cost of spinning up new objects constantly, and keep you from having to wait until the garbage collector to run before releasing the memory.

   There are a lot of examples and patterns to look at for creating object pools in actionscript. It would be easier if AS supported generics, but even without them its still pretty straight forward.
3. **Eagerly dispose of huge objects**

   This goes directly against the advice in the previous point, but for huge objects, you don't want them hanging around in memory forever. I'm referring to things like `BitmapData`, when you are done with them (for the foreseeable future), tear them down and null them out, and let the garbage collector clean it up.

   When you need them again, rebuild them. Yes, you will take a slight performance hit, but memory on mobile devices is precious and don't waste it by keeping around a 2mb bitmapdata object that only ever appears on the loading screen. Throw it away.
4. **Null out references you don't need anymore**

   Take some time and try to really understand what the garbage collector needs to do its work, and how its decides which objects can and cannot be thrown away. Try to avoid self referential objects/circular references, while the CG can normally figure it out, sometimes it might need a litle hand holding.
5. **Evaluate every time you use `new`** [Related to 2]

   Again using a memory profiler will help for this step, but make sure that every time you instantiate a new object, you need to instantiate a new object. It can be very easy to get lazy when developing for a PC, just throwing new objects into the pool and letting the CG sort it out. See if there are good caching strategies (object pooling, or just reference caching) if its small. And if its a HUGE object that you are building up and tearing down often, it might be time to try to come up with a better architectural solution.

As far as I know, if you get to the point where iOS thinks the memory is low, its already too late. Last time I checked, the framework will try to run the CG when it thinks its running out of memory, and if it can't free up enough memory to continue, it fails out. Do your best to try to avoid getting to the point where the operating system thinks the only safe option is to terminate your thread.

Comment: hey there - these all seem to be very good hints on how to use less memory, thanks for those. But still, is there any way to be notified when memory is running out? I think iOS informs applications when the remaining memory is low - any way to get that info into AS3? Or is there any way to catch a failed "new"?

Comment: @Mat you might be able to use [System.freeMemory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#freeMemory) to keep an eye on it manually if you like. But you should really be trying to manage your memory usage *before* it becomes a problem, not after the OS is already concerned about it. -- if you have gotten to the point where a `new` fails due to lack of memory, it is *wayyyy* too late to do anything about it.

Comment: not really - when coding for iOS, you can still free some memory and display an error message at least for example (instead of letting the app just crash). System.freeMemory doesn't seem to be helpful, as it's always a very small number independantly of how much memory the app uses at the moment. Also, crashes seem to depend on how many other applications are running in the background. Of course it's good to keep memory consumption low, but it would be better to have at least a way to know why the app is crashing (at least writing a out-of-memory to a log file or something like this)

Comment: get the miner (http://www.sociodox.com/theminer/) instead of flash builder. has the same profiling tools (from the flash.sampler package), and as a bonus, eclipse is not on your machine

Comment: @Mat `System.freeMemory` will always be a relatively low number, as it's not the amount of memory that's free on the os, but the amount of memory free in the current page of memory allocated to Flash

Comment: @divillysausages: yes i thoght something like that already, so the value is pretty much useless.. the only more or less useful number seems to be the private memory - though it's also the most black-box thingy one (as the garbage collector for example doesn't seem to influence this number much. i guess there's a lot of Air-internal memory handling responsible for this number, independant of AS3 objects). At the moment the app is most likely to crash when this number is somewhere above 60MB.

Comment: @Mat "at least writing a out-of-memory to a log file or something like this" it does. http://aplus.rs/apple/how-to-find-crash-logs-for-iphone-applications-on-mac-vista-and-xp/

Comment: And this weekend I might look at a way to wrap an ane around the sdk `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, and see if that is useful.